# Comparar el mes en seleccion Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

necesito comparar la fecha solo los que se tengan en el mes del sistema y para esto realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
                        var lstConcepto = (from m in context.SMT_CONCEPTOBASICO
                                       where m.CODIGOENTIDAD.Contains(getCodEntidad) 
                                       && m.FECHAINICIAL == ConceptoTo.FechaInicial 
                                       && m.FECHASISTEMA == ConceptoTo.FechaSistema.Month
                                       && !m.VALORALFANUMERICO.Contains("Total")
                                       select m).ToList();
```

No encuentro la forma como hacer que m.FECHASISTEMA.MONTH a la fecha del objeto.

**&& m.FECHASISTEMA == ConceptoTo.FechaSistema.Month** aca me sale error comparar datetime e int... como convierto m.FECHASISTEMA En month??

**UPDATE**
la opción de m.FECHASISTEMA.Month saca error como se indica en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `m.FECHASISTEMA.Month == ConceptoTo.FechaSistema.Month` no te funciona?

Comment: Parece ser que .FechaSistema es la fecha completa y luego queres comparar el mes que seria un int nada mas. Proba como dice @Lobos.

Comment: @Lobos si habia colocado la opcion .Month como tu dices pero me aparece el error que muestra en la imagen.

Comment: @RamiroBarone Si solo deseo comparar mes, bueno también año y mes pero me saca error como lo indica la imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que FECHASISTEMA es de tipo `Nullable`. Por eso en el error aparece como `DateTime?` con el `?` al final.

Para leer el valor debes hacerlo así:

```
m.FECHASISTEMA?.Month
```

[Referencia Nullable C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

**Actualización:**

Crea una variable y guarda ahí el valor de la fecha para usarlo en la consulta:

```
var lstConcepto = (from m in context.SMT_CONCEPTOBASICO
     let fechaSistema = m.FECHASISTEMA.HasValue ? m.FECHASISTEMA.Value.Month : 0
     where m.CODIGOENTIDAD.Contains(getCodEntidad) 
     && m.FECHAINICIAL == ConceptoTo.FechaInicial 
     && fechaSistema == ConceptoTo.FechaSistema.Month
     && !m.VALORALFANUMERICO.Contains("Total")
     select m).ToList();
```

Comment: ya el error cambio a **una expresión lambda de árbol de expresión no puede contener un operador de propagación NULL**

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: si resulto con la variable!! Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Siempre que `m.FECHASISTEMA` sea `DateTime` puedes hacer la comparación de la siguiente forma

```
&& m.FECHASISTEMA.Date.Month == ConceptoTo.FechaSistema.Month
```

A´si, tu código debería quedar

```
var lstConcepto = (from m in context.SMT_CONCEPTOBASICO
    where m.CODIGOENTIDAD.Contains(getCodEntidad) 
    && m.FECHAINICIAL == ConceptoTo.FechaInicial 
    && m.FECHASISTEMA.Date.Month == ConceptoTo.FechaSistema.Month
    && !m.VALORALFANUMERICO.Contains("Total")
    select m).ToList();
```

Comment: aun sigue saliendo error como el que indica en la imagen,